# Sorting and Paging a Gridview with generated datareader

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been looking for some examples on how to sort a gridview with custom generated datareader.

Here's how I bind gridview with datareader.

```
        sqlConn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        gridBookings.DataSource = reader;
        gridBookings.DataBind();
        sqlConn.Close();
```

---

And this is the sorted event handler of the gridview

```
protected void gridBookings_Sorted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridBookings.DataBind();
}
```

---

Here's the gridview markup.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridBookings" runat="server"  CssClass="zebra-striped" 
        EmptyDataText="No data available, sir" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" 
        ClientIDMode="Static" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" 
        onsorted="gridBookings_Sorted">
<columns>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="BookingID" DataField="booking_id" SortExpression="booking_id"/><asp:BoundField HeaderText="CustomerID" DataField="cus_id" SortExpression="cus_id" />
<!--More bound fields-->
</columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

---

And this is the error I get when I click the link buttons in the header column.

> The GridView 'gridBookings' fired event Sorting which wasn't handled.

Any ideas?

PS. On the side question, how can I show the blank gridview with empty rows when any data hasn't bind to it?

Answer (score 1):

You're subscribing to the "Sorted" event... but you also need to subscribe to the "Sorting" event. You should really upgrade to a newer version of ASP.NET :)

Answer (score 1):

Gridview's **Sorting** event occurs when the hyperlink to sort a column is clicked, but **before** the GridView control handles the sort operation. **Sorted** event occurs when the hyperlink to sort a column is clicked, but **after** the GridView control handles the sort operation. Generally we use gridviews sorting event for sorting items in gridview. Check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx#Y416/%22this%22) link for a detailed example of sorting items in gridview

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridBookings" runat="server"  CssClass="zebra-striped" 
    EmptyDataText="No data available, sir" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" 
    ClientIDMode="Static" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" 
    onsorted="gridBookings_Sorted"
    onsorting="gridBookings_Sorting">

protected void gridBookings_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    //handled onsorting
}
```